# Zip twice with password and send as email attachment using Node.js, Lambda & SES

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am trying to zip a file twice using *archiver-zip-encrypted* node.js module. When I try local machine the file is able to zip twice with password in encrypted AES256. But when I try the same in Lambda, it is not behaving as same locally.  I tried attaching both the file files and I noticed the first zip file has the actual file inside but I have issue in creating the 2nd zip file as it has a blank file inside it.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var ses = new aws.SES();
const archiver = require('archiver');
const stream = require('stream')
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

    const filepath = event.filepath;
    const filename =  event.file;
    const email = event.email;
    const bucket = "BUCKETNAME";
    const filepathZip = '/tmp/'+filename +'.zip';
    const filenameZip = filename +'.zip';

    var s3 = new aws.S3();
    var options = {
        Bucket:bucket,
        Key: 'files/' + filename
    };

    var fileStream = s3.getObject(options).createReadStream();

    archiver.registerFormat('zip-encrypted', require("archiver-zip-encrypted"));
    var output = fs.createWriteStream(filepathZip);

    var randampassword = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    let archive = archiver.create('zip-encrypted', {zlib: {level: 8}, encryptionMethod: 'aes256', password: randampassword });
    output.on('close', function() {
        console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes ');
        console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
        console.log(randampassword);
    });
    archive.on('err', function(err) {
        throw err;
    });
 var FinalZip = '/tmp/'+filename +'_final.zip'; 
  let archive_final = archiver.create('zip-encrypted', {zlib: {level: 8}, encryptionMethod: 'aes256', password: randampassword });
  var output_final = fs.createWriteStream(FinalZip)
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            archive.pipe(output); 
            archive.append(fileStream, { name: filename }).finalize();
            archive_final.pipe(output_final);
            archive_final
        .file(filepathZip, { name: filenameZip })
        .finalize(); 
        }
      ]);
    getS3File('BUCKETNAME', 'test.txt')
        .then(function (fileData) {
            var mailOptions = {
                from: 'SENDER',
                subject: 'This is an email sent from a Lambda function!',
                html: `<p>You got a contact message from: <b>${event.email}</b> paasword: <b>${randampassword}</b></p>`,
                to: 'RECEIVER',
                // bcc: Any BCC address you want here in an array,
                attachments: [
                    {
                        filename: "attach.zip",
                        path: filepathZip
                    }
                ]
            };

            console.log('Creating SES transporter');
            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                SES: ses
            });

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log('Error sending email');
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Email sent successfully');
                    callback();
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log('Error getting attachment from S3');
            callback(error);
        });
};
```

Comment: Don't you have to do `archive_final.append`

Comment: I have used ```archive_final.file(filepathZip, { name: filenameZip }).finalize();``` to zip the 2nd archive

Comment: Do you have to use waterfall